# How to create a variable which increments by 1 for each checkbox which is ticked

Tags: php, function, increment

I am trying to create a function which returns a boolean value (1 or 0) when a checkbox is ticked....no problems here. I also want it to include a session variable which increments by 1 for every checkbox which is ticked. When I echo out the value of $_SESSION ['counter'] after submitting the form $_SESSION ['counter'] remains at zero or whichever value I initially set it to. Can anybody see where I am going wrong? Many thanks for any help in advance!

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
} 


$_SESSION['counter']= 0; 


function checkbox_boolean ($checkboxID){ 

   $checkboxID= 0;
   if(isset($_POST[$checkboxID])){
       $checkboxID = 1;
       $_SESSION['counter']++;
   }
} 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo $_SESSION['counter'];


    checkbox_boolean ('slot1');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot2');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot3');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot4');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot5');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot6');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot7');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot8');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes in your code, see the suggested edits

```
?php
    // dont need to test anything just call session_start()
    session_start();   

   // initialise only if not already in existance
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 0; 
    }


function checkbox_boolean ($checkboxID){ 
   // this just destroyed whatever was passed in the $checkboxID parameter
   // $checkboxID= 0;  
   if(isset($_POST[$checkboxID])){
       // This does nothing useful
       //$checkboxID = 1;
       $_SESSION['counter']++;
   }
} 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo 'Session counter before = ' . $_SESSION['counter'];

    checkbox_boolean ('slot1');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot2');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot3');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot4');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot5');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot6');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot7');
    checkbox_boolean ('slot8');

    echo 'Session counter after = ' . $_SESSION['counter'];
}

?>
```

Comment: A big thank you to Raphael diSanto and RiggsFolly! I have been chasing my tail with this for a couple of days, so i really appreciate your help. To RiggsFolly, many thanks for pointing out the errors!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the

```
$_SESSION['counter']= 0;
```

to zero every time the PHP script gets called. Doesn't matter what it was before, this line always resets it back to zero.

Change this to only initialize it if it doesn't already exist. Something like..

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
  $_SESSION['counter']= 0; 
}
```